# How to Upload an Animated GIF in Twitter for IOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, twitter, share

I have a GIF image and want to share it in twitter but unfortunately it's not working.

When i posted the image using the twitter api on the *dev.twitter.com* site it works fine and animates.

However i want to post the image using the Twitter IOS App/API. Does anybody know how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please explain why down vote ?

Comment: There is a badge for the first down vote, so some members go for it if your question is easy to understand or does not have code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
- (void)postImage:(UIImage *)image withStatus:(NSString *)status url:(NSURL*)urlData {

   // UIImage *img = [UIImage animatedImageNamed:@"test.gif" duration:3.0];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update_with_media.json"];
    NSMutableDictionary *paramater = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    //set the parameter here. to see others acceptable parameters find it at twitter API here : http://bit.ly/Occe6R
    [paramater setObject:status forKey:@"status"];

    ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
    ACAccountType *accountType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];

    [accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType options:nil completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
        if (granted == YES) {

            NSArray *accountsArray = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:accountType];

            if ([accountsArray count] > 0) {
                ACAccount *twitterAccount = [accountsArray lastObject];

                SLRequest *postRequest = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter requestMethod:SLRequestMethodPOST URL:url parameters:paramater];

                NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:urlData]; // GIF89a file

                [postRequest addMultipartData:imageData withName:@"media[]" type:@"image/gif" filename:@"animated.gif"];

                [postRequest setAccount:twitterAccount]; // or  postRequest.account = twitterAccount;

                [postRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
                    NSString *output = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"HTTP response status: %i", [urlResponse statusCode]];
                    NSLog(@"output = %@",output);
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                    });

                }];
            }

        }
    }];
}
```

**Just call above method like this**

```
[self postImage:nil withStatus:@"Your Text" url:assetURL]
```

Comment: how to upload audio file?

Answer (score 1):

Actually update_with_media is deprecated.

From now you need to use upload.json + update.json only. It is a 2-tier process.

I wrote a tutorial on how to do this with complete codes. See here:
http://xcodenoobies.blogspot.my/2016/01/how-to-using-slrequest-to-upload-image.html